# Can not Access Aloquent Relationship Laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying use aloquent relationship to access database. However, all relationship returned Null/Empty.

The following is my code:

**ProductModel**

```
class ProductModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "products";
    public $timestamps = true;

    function prices(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductPriceModel::class,"id_kiotviet_product","id_kiotviet")
                    ->select("*")
                    ->where("status",1)
                    ->where("update_kiotviet","!=","outofdate");
    }
    function unit(){
        return $this->hasOne(ProductUnitModel::class,"id_kiotviet_product","id_kiotviet")
                    ->select("*")
                    ->where("update_kiotviet","!=","outofdate");
    }
    function attributes(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttributeModel::class,"id_kiotviet_product","id_kiotviet")
                    ->select("*")
                    ->where("update_kiotviet","!=","outofdate");
    }
    function invetories(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductInventoryModel::class,"id_kiotviet_product","id_kiotviet")
                    ->select("*")
                    ->where("status",1)
                    ->where("update_kiotviet","!=","outofdate");
    }
    function images(){
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImageModel::class,"id_kiotviet_product","id_kiotviet")
                    ->select("*")
                    ->where("update_kiotviet","!=","outofdate");
    }
    function ratings(){
        return $this->hasMany(RatingProductModel::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
    function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(CommentModel::class, 'item_id', 'id')
                    ->where('type', 'product');
    }
    
    function productLv1(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductLv1Model::class, 'id_kiotviet_lv1', 'id_kiotviet');
    }
    function productLv2(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductLv2Model::class, 'id_kiotviet_lv2', 'id_kiotviet');
    }
    function productLv3(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductLv3Model::class, 'id_kiotviet_lv3', 'id_kiotviet');
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public function getGoogleActivedMasterProducts($targetedDatetime, $isWholesaler = false){
    $idKiotvietBook = 1000000;
    if($isWholesaler){
        $idKiotvietBook = 3002;
    }

    $products =
    $this->model
        ->select("*")
        ->whereNull("id_master_product")
        ->where('status',1)
        ->where("allow_sale",1)
        ->where("update_kiotviet","!=","outofdate")
        ->whereHas(
            "productLv1", function($query){
                $query->where('status',1);
                $query->where('update_kiotviet', '!=', "outofdate");
            }
        )
        ->whereHas(
            "productLv2", function($query){
                $query->where('status',1);
                $query->where('update_kiotviet', '!=', "outofdate");
            }
        )
        ->whereHas(
            "productLv3", function($query){
                $query->where('status',1);
                $query->where('update_kiotviet', '!=', "outofdate");
            }
        )
        ;

        if($targetedDatetime){
            $products = $products->where("updated_at",">=",$targetedDatetime);
        }

        $products = $products
            ->with([
                "ratings.user" => function ($query) {
                    $query->select('id', 'email', 'image', 'first_name', 'last_name','social_img');
                },
                "prices" => function($query) use ($idKiotvietBook) {
                    $query->where('id_kiotviet_book', $idKiotvietBook);
                },
                "unit",
                "invetories",
                "attributes",
                "images"
            ])

            ->withCount([
                'ratings as totalRating',
                'ratings as oneRating' => function($query){
                    $query->where('point', 1);
                },
                'ratings as twoRating' => function($query){
                    $query->where('point', 2);
                },
                'ratings as threeRating' => function($query){
                    $query->where('point', 3);
                },
                'ratings as fourRating' => function($query){
                    $query->where('point', 4);
                },
                'ratings as fiveRating' => function($query){
                    $query->where('point', 5);
                },
            ])
            ->withAvg('ratings as averagePoint', 'point')
            ->get();

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            if($product->id_kiotviet == "3910570"){
                dd($product);
                break;

            }
        }
    return $products;
}
```

**All of Reponse's Relations reurned null/empty:**

[image]

**I tried on myphpAdmin too:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I found the root of issue that there are a lot of records on database, it maybe make aloquent can not load all relationship's data. Currently I am using CHUNK to hanlde again.